# Add Twitter Bootstrap Popover via Ajax, with Rails

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to add a popover via an ajax call with rails.  I see in firebug that the content loads fine, but the popover isn't loading.

All other popovers work on the page, and if I reload the page, the popover works too...but it just doesn't work on the ajax call.  What am I missing?

update.js

```
$("#new-pins").append("<div class='pinimage' data-original-title=''><img src='/images/<%= @changes[0] %>.png' class='pinimage' data-content='hello' data-original-title=''></a></div>")
```

show.html popover javascript:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('.pinimage').popover({ html : true });
});
</script>
```

Here's what loads after the ajax call:

```
<div class="pinimage" data-original-title="">
   <img class="pinimage" data-original-title="" data-content="hello" src="/images/card.png">
</div>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: If you put a `console.log("Testing")` inside the second function, does the console show something? Does the `.pinimage` exist before you establish the event? And also, if you put `jquery` in the tags in this type of questions, probably somebody that knows more than me will answer faster hehe.

Comment: It might help to post your controller code, and your form code too.  My first guess is that the edit form might need a :remote => true passed to it.

Comment: will post the controller code, but the controller seems to be acting fine (it has remote => true in it), and all of the right html loads, but for some reason the popover won't work.

Comment: @pigueiras...i tried loading the div with ajax and have it preexisting in the view before, but didn't make a difference.  Do I somehow have to call the popover javascript function again after the ajax call?

Comment: looks like I had to pre-load an empty .pinimage and then replace the empty content.  popovers must somehow be pre-loaded

Comment: I have a similar situation. I use jQuery get to load in some content that includes popovers - they won't fire when loaded in dynamically for some reason. Still trying to get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604829/ruby-on-rails-twitter-bootstrap-popover-not-working-correctly-after-jquery-updat) and finally got it to work when I realized that I was calling the jquery on document load but I had to call it again in the .js.erb file.